# I'm using sh404SEF on HostGator. What should I do with my .htaccess?

Tags: sh404sef, seo, .htaccess-configuration

I'm new to sh404SEF, but I understand it is widely used.  I host with HostGator.

I'm using sh404SEF primarily to generate search engine friendly URL's.

sh404SEF advertises that I can do this without modifying the .htaccess file, but while this might be the easiest approach, is it the `best approach?`

Assuming that I have no issue with having to modify the .htaccess file

1. Should I make any modifications to it?
2. What modifications should I make?
3. What are the impact of those modifications?

Answer (score 3):

1) Not really.

2) From a configuration perspective you don't need to change anything in the .htaccess file for proper and optimal functionality of sh404sef.

From an "SEO" perspective, there are some things I would recommend. Mainly ensure that you are properly redirecting non www to www (or vise versa) using this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159088/how-to-modify-htaccess-file-to-always-redirect-to-www

Make sure you add it below the `RewriteEngine On` line.

3) Redirects non-www URLs to www URLs as a 301 redirect. Gives some improved SEO juice so Google doesn't give SEO authority to more than one URL.

Comment: I would not recommend to use .htaccess to redirect non-www to www in case if you use sh404SEF.
You can redirect non-www to www by going to Components > sh404SEF > Configurations > Advanced > Advanced Component Configuration. Use the dropdown here to redirect non-www to www

Comment: I knew sh404 did this, but my feeling has been if it can be done at the server level via .htaccess I figured its better than doing it at the php level with sh404. Not sure if it really matters, but I've tended to prefer going directly to .htaccess since I felt it's executed sooner.

Comment: Quick note: I think you're assuming the user is using the Joomla htaccess.txt renamed to .htaccess.  sh404SEF actually can run without using the Joomla router htaccess.txt .  If the asker is saying they are using the root HostGator htaccess file that doesn't actually include the mod rewrite code, then we've made a critically incorrect assumption.

Comment: @ I believe your approach, going directly to the .htaccess level will provide better performance and answers part 3 of the question.  My concerns are that although sh404SEF might make things easier by by-passing the .htaccess, it's not necessarily the 'best way go' - these are the types of answers I'm looking for - so thank you!

Comment: @ToniMarie - I will look into the specific configuration of HostGator to check about mod rewrite code and see if I can provide some clarification on this.